# I want to use a specific symbol

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm writing math notes, and I would like to use the symbol for the letter T that appears in this picture (seen in a TeX.StackExchange post): [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/980yM.jpg)

The symbol I want is in the line "**Calligraphic**: UPRIGHT: euler (Euler script)". How can I load it?

Note that I'm not interested in changing all symbols in my document. I just want to use that T perhaps once in the entire document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

The font you're referring to is Euler Script and is provided by the `euscript` package.

In it we find

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuScript{U}{eus}{m}{n}
```

For a single letter it would be a waste of resources to define a new math alphabet, but we have all the needed data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\specialT}{\mathord{\text{\usefont{U}{eus}{m}{n}T}}}

\begin{document}

$\specialT$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is a way of doing it by using "\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}".

Comment: @user3011 - It's the same as shown above. I.e., run `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` as usual, and separately run `\DeclareRobustCommand{\specialT}{\mathord{\text{\usefont{U}{eus}{m}{n}T}}}`.